# how to stream high quality video and audio from iPhone to remote server through Internet

Tags: iphone, ios, video-streaming, avfoundation, avcapturesession

I am seeking the following three items, which I cannot find on STACKOVERFLOW or anywhere:

1. sample code for AVFoundation capturing to file chunks (~10seconds) that are ready for compression?
2. sample code for compressing the video and audio for transmisison across the Internet?
   ffmpeg?
3. sample code for HTTP Live Streaming sending files from iPhone to Internet server?

My goal is to use the iPhone as a high quality AV camcorder that streams to a remote server.
If the intervening data rate bogs down, files should buffer at the iPhone.

thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can use AVAssetWriter to encode a MP4 file of your desired length. The AV media will be encoded into the container in H264/AAC. You could then simply upload this to a remote server. If you wanted you could segment the video for HLS streaming, but keep in mind that HLS is designed as a server->client streaming protocol. There is no notion of push as far as I know. You would have to create a custom server to accept pushing of segmented video streams (which does not really make a lot of sense given the way HLS is designed. See the [RFC Draft](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-pantos-http-live-streaming-08). A better approach might be to simply upload the MP4(s) via a TCP socket and have your server segment the video for streaming to client viewers. This could be easily done with FFmpeg either on the command line, or via a custom program.

I also wanted to add that if you try and stream 720p video over a cellular connection your app will more then likely get rejected for excessive data use.

Answer (score 0):

Capture Video and Audio using AVFouncation. You can specify the Audio and Video codecs to kCMVideoCodecType_H264 and kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC, Frame sizes, Frame rates in AVCaptureformatDescription. It will give you Compressed H264 video and AAC aduio.

Encapsulate this and transmit to server using any RTP servers like Live555 Media.